# To "lay lodged" — what does it mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've googled and looked it up in every dictionary I know, and I can find "lay" and I can find "lodge", but I can't seem to work out the meaning of the two words together.

The context is this poem by Robert Frost:

> The rain to the wind said,
>   You push and I'll pelt.'
>   They so smote the garden bed
>   That the flowers actually knelt,
>   And *lay lodged*--though not dead.
>   I know how the flowers felt.

Comment: *Lay lodged* is not a set-phrase or idiom. The phrase means what the words individually stand for.

Comment: As *knelt* is the past of *kneel*, here *lay* is the past of *lie*.  They simply lay there where smitten, beaten down but not quite dead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lodged) has this definition for lodged:

> .3. to beat (as a crop) flat to the ground

And in the poem, this is exactly what happens to the flowers - the rain and the wind beat them until they *lay down* flat on the ground. They are not dead, just lodged.

Comment: so "lay" as in "lie down"? Right. Of course. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Compare with the second half of the conjunction, which can be expanded to "but not lay dead". "Lay dead" is a much more common expression and can be used to understand the construction. (See http://gog.is/lay+dead)

Comment: The OED supports MW with ‘to throw down on the ground, lay flat. Now only of rain or wind: To beat down crops.’